# A member test using Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I was having trouble understanding recursion. I'm looking for some feedback here to see how this program looks.

Question :::
Write a recursive Boolean function named isMember. The function should accept three parameters: an array of integers, an integer indicating the number of elements in the array, and an integer value to be searched for. The function should return true if the value is found in the array or false if the value is not found. Demonstrate the use of the function in a program that asks the user to enter an array of numbers and a value to be searched for.

What I have::

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isMember(int[],int,int);


int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int numSearch;
    int elementz[SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Element " << i + 1 << "\t";
        cin >> elementz[i];
    }

    cout << "Enter element to search\n";
    cin >> numSearch;

    bool value = isMember(elementz,SIZE,numSearch);

    if(value ==1)
        cout << "Element is found\n";
    else
        cout << "Element not found\n";

    return 0;
}


bool isMember(int arr[], int sizze, int num)
{
    if(arr[sizze] == num)
        return true;
    else
        isMember(arr,sizze -1, num);
}
```

Comment: You'll need a false case for your isMember function (when sizze is -1). Other than that - yes, it's a recursive function. It should return isMember(arr, sizze - 1, num) rather than just call isMember(arr, sizze - 1, num) so the return value can move up the call stack to the original calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return if the `if` clause is false. Also, keep in mind that indexes start at 0, not 1 (and why `sizze`?).

I would recommend starting with an array of 3 values, rather than of 10. That way you''ll be able to manually follow and unfold the successive calls.

Answer (score 0):

In order for recursions to work, you need not only a "conditional stop", but an inconditional stop too.

In your example, you only provided a conditional stop. To make it work correctly, try something like this:

```
bool isMember(int arr[], int sizze, int num)
{
    if ( sizze < 0 )  // "inconditional stop"
        return false;

    if(arr[sizze] == num)  // conditional stop. It could happen or not
        return true;
    else
        isMember(arr,sizze -1, num);
}
```

Comment: Alright sweet, thank you. One more quick question. Will there ever be situation when the Element isn't found?

Comment: It depends on how you populate your array